# My data groups are not staying in order on my bar chart in R

Tags: r

I am making a bar chart with sd error bars on R but my Months (9, 10, 11, 12) won't stay in the correct order when placed on the graph. Does anybody know how to make it so they don't swap order?[image]

```
library(tidyverse)
library(RColorBrewer)
d <- structure(list(Month = c("9", "9", "9", "10", "10", "10", "11", "11", "11", "12", "12", "12"), genus = c("Crustacean", "Mollusc", "Seaweed", "Crustacean", "Mollusc", "Seaweed","Crustacean", "Mollusc", "Seaweed","Crustacean", "Mollusc", "Seaweed"), 
                    shannon = c(0,
                                1.1594324,
                                1.37245692,
                                0,
                                0.84868133,
                                1.54327422,
                                0.06432965,
                                1.1748941,
                                1.54612048,
                                0,
                                1.1045688,
                                1.7212854),
                    sd = c(0,
                           0.3288658,
                           0.7824814,
                           0,
                           0.8148536,
                           0.5015486,
                           0.1286593,
                           0.446148,
                           0.800392,
                           0,
                           0.1804363,
                           0.4421767)), 
               row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = "data.frame")

d %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = genus, y = shannon, fill = Month)) +
  geom_col(width = 0.5,
           position = position_dodge(0.5)) + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = shannon - sd, ymax = shannon + sd),
                width = 0.2,
                position = position_dodge(0.5)) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Blues") +
  theme_minimal()
```

Comment: You either need to convert them to numbers (as.numeric), or factors in the correct order: `d$Month <- factor(d$Month, 9:12)`

Answer (score 2):

Since month is of type character, the automatic order is alphabetical. You can change this using `reorder()`:

```
d %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = genus, y = shannon, fill = reorder(Month, as.numeric(Month)))) +
  geom_col(width = 0.5,
           position = position_dodge(0.5)) + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = shannon - sd, ymax = shannon + sd),
                width = 0.2,
                position = position_dodge(0.5)) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Blues", name = 'Month') +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here comes a base R solution. Beforehand you should look where your months get coded as character, for this example we may convert it to numeric.

```
d$Month <- as.numeric(d$Month)

b <- barplot(shannon ~ Month + genus, d, beside=T, ylim=c(0, max(rowSums(d[3:4]))),
             col=hcl.colors(4, 'Blues', rev=T), legend.text=unique(d$Month), 
             args.legend=list(x='topleft', title='Month', bty='n'))
with(d[order(d$genus), ], arrows(b, shannon - sd, b, shannon + sd, code=3,
                                 angle=90, length=.05, xpd=TRUE)))
```

[image]

R will warn you that in this example some arrows have length zero and therefore aren't plotted.

---

*Data:*

```
d <- structure(list(Month = c("9", "9", "9", "10", "10", "10", "11", 
"11", "11", "12", "12", "12"), genus = c("Crustacean", "Mollusc", 
"Seaweed", "Crustacean", "Mollusc", "Seaweed", "Crustacean", 
"Mollusc", "Seaweed", "Crustacean", "Mollusc", "Seaweed"), shannon = c(0, 
1.1594324, 1.37245692, 0, 0.84868133, 1.54327422, 0.06432965, 
1.1748941, 1.54612048, 0, 1.1045688, 1.7212854), sd = c(0, 0.3288658, 
0.7824814, 0, 0.8148536, 0.5015486, 0.1286593, 0.446148, 0.800392, 
0, 0.1804363, 0.4421767)), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = "data.frame")
```